# Malaysian multiple-entry visa

Tags: visas, malaysia

My travel itinerary:

- September 9: India to Malaysia
- September 13: Malaysia to Singapore
- September 16: Singapore to Malaysia (Kuala Lumpur KLIA 2)
- September 16: Malaysia (Kuala Lumpur KLIA) to India

I have confirmed tickets.

What type of visa do I need to apply for Malaysia?

> India Nationals: eVISA MEV 15 and 30 Days.
>   The eVISA MEV 15 and 30 days for Indian Nationals will be closing on 29th July 2018 and in replacement, the eVISA SEV 30 days will be available starting 30th July 2018.

Multiple-entry visa applications are no longer accepted after 29th July.

Possible options I can think of:

1. Apply for 2 single-entry visas (e-visa or eNTRI).
2. Apply for a single-entry visa for the first flight on September 9, and a transit visa on September 16.

Is there any other option? If any of the above two options are applicable, what are the conditions for applying for those visas?

Comment: VTC: OP has asked and answered the question.